# Solving a linear algebra problem containing minimal polynomial degree

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, polynomials

> Consider a set of three-dimensional points ${\left\{{\left(a,ab,abc\right)}~\middle\vert~a,b,c\in\mathbb{N_+}\land a+b+c\leqslant2023\right\}}$. If there exists a non-zero real polynomial $\operatorname{\it P}{\left(x,y,z\right)}$ that vanishes at each point in such a set, find the minimum of $\deg\mathop{P}$.

Evidently, this can be solved by certain advanced *olympiad-esque* "tricks". For instance, first, one may note that ${\left(x-1\right)}{\left(x-2\right)}{\left(x-3\right)}\dotsm{\left(x-2021\right)}$ meets the constraint (hence the minimum of deg(P) must not be greater than 2021).
However, the remaining part is, in effect, a dirty *technical* work; many times one really does not have enough intelligence to complete it (or even ***cannot*** observe the instance above). Therefore, I decide to solve this problem with the aid of Mathematica.

Actually, I intend to solve it **without too much** a priori knowledge of the linear algebra (in other words, *without* manually calculating the general results in advance).
Here is my attempt (from degree＝1, check if the corresponding matrix has a non-trivial null space):

```
lowestexponent\[InvisibleApplication] 
  bound_Integer?(GreaterEqualThan[3]) := 
 Block[{ptst = 
    N[FoldList[Times, Transpose[
      ParallelArray[
        Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[#, {3}] &, 
        bound - 2, 3, Join]]](*transpose of the 3D point set*)], aux, 
   deg = 0 + 1, temp}, 
  aux[2] = 
   Join[aux[1] = 
     Join[aux[0] = ConstantArray[0, {1, 3}], IdentityMatrix[3]], 
    FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, 2]]; 
  aux[n_?Internal`PositiveMachineIntegerQ] := 
   aux[n] = 
    Join[aux[n - 1], 
     Join @@ Permutations /@ PadLeft[IntegerPartitions[n, 3]]]; 
  NestWhile[++deg &, , 
   MatrixRank[
      Developer`ToPackedArray[
       Thread[Rationalize[
         Evaluate[
            GroebnerBasis`FromDistributedTermsList[{Transpose[{aux[
                 deg], ConstantArray[1, 
                 temp = Binomial[deg + 3,3]]}], {#1, #2, #3}}, 
             List]] & @@ ptst]]]] == 
     temp(*until the coefficient matrix becomes rank-deficient*)&]]

lowestexponent[1*^1] (*This works.*)
(* 8 *)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to execute `lowestexponent[2023]`, my low-end computer just hangs …. Any ideas of improving my code? Or is there any better implementation?

Comment: I assumed you had a typo in the phrasing of the task – please check that I fixed it correctly.

Comment: @Domen Thanks. I have corrected it.